# python webserver https certificate

Tags: python, webserver

I want to run an Python webserver on linux (RedHat or CentOS) using https.  I got an (internal) certificate, and obtained the requisite intermediate and root certificates.  I cat'd them all into a single file, server.pem.

Here's my code:

```
    httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    cf = '/home/degenaro/workspace/certs/server.pem'
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile=cf, server_side=True)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Here's the result:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File "/home/degenaro/workspace/web.py", line 66, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "/home/degenaro/workspace/web.py", line 56, in main
>     httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile=cf, server_side=True)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 934, in wrap_socket
>     ciphers=ciphers)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 547, in __init__
>     self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
> ssl.SSLError: [PEM] ASN1 lib (_ssl.c:2574)
> ```

What me do wrong?

Comment: whats up with the port number `4443`? the default port for https is 443

Comment: Are you suggesting that changing the port number to 443 will remedy my malady?

Comment: idk try it and find out? I've never used the simple server really. You might be better served using a something like flask if you want it working with good defaults out the gate

Comment: I'm not sure I can use 443, unless I am root?  I'm also skeptical that this will fix the problem, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying is that `SSL_CTX_check_private_key` failed; thus, the private key is not correct.

Make sure that:

- your keys are correct;
- permission of private key is `600`;
- your port opened and cert server is available

Comment: -rw-------. 1 degenaro degenaro 8527 Jul  9 13:04 /home/degenaro//workspace/certs/server.pem

Comment: The short answer give @Iddo. The more information: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/56074/how-does-rsa-public-and-private-key-structure-look-like

Comment: The error says that ASN decoder can't to read your key. So the format of your key is not correct, like described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One

Answer (score 0):

first of all it would help if you could provide the release versions of the python you are using as well as the OpenSSL library it uses.

It seems that the error is in the format of the .pem file. does it have the following structure? ([as described here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html#ssl-certificates))

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (certificate for your server)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the certificate for the CA)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the root certificate for the CA's issuer)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

also from the comments I gather that the server-certificate is invalid, perhaps due to wrong encoding. please try:

> openssl x509 -inform DER -in [current_server_cert.pem] -out [new_server_cert.pem]
>   [as shown here][2](https://support.cloudbolt.io/hc/en-us/articles/115002452786-HOWTO-Convert-a-CER-file-to-CRT)

Comment: `[degenaro@oc0668325081 ~]$ python -V
Python 2.7.5`

Comment: `[degenaro@oc0668325081 ~]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`

Comment: All 3 entries are -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- {stuff} -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: checking the 3 individual certs:

Comment: openssl verify ./caintermediatecert.pem  OK

Comment: openssl verify ./carootcert.pem  OK

Comment: openssl verify ./cloud-ducc-test.pem  unable to load certificate

Comment: @user2133121 is it possible the server cert is not PEM encoded, rather it is DER encoded?
please try "openssl x509 -inform DER -in cloud-ducc-test.pem -out cloud-ducc-test-new.pem" and use the output file as the server certificate when building the chain